# Multiple dropdown buttons in a panel-body opening at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.7 and I have two buttons inside a panel-body, but whenever I click either of the buttons, both of the buttons opens their dropdown menus.

```
 <div class="static">
   <div class ="container">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
               <li class="active"><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Flight Times</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">My Trips</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="panel-body">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1"
               data-toggle="dropdown">From
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">London Stanstead Airport (<strong>STN</strong>)</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2"
               data-toggle="dropdown">To
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Manchester (<strong>MAN</strong>)</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Glasgow (<strong>GLA</strong>)</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Dublin (<strong>DUB</strong>)</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Paris (<strong>CDG</strong>)</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Madrid (<strong>MAD</strong>)</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Brussels (<strong>BRU</strong>)</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to wrap each button dropdown into a .btn-group itself, like this : 
https://www.bootply.com/ErHpvikz6x

You can check the details in Bootstrap documentation : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/